# How to fetch data from endpoint in Sveltekit version v1.0.0-next.287

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Yesterday I updated SvelteKit version from v1.0.0-next.241 to v1.0.0-next.287, and since I cannot fetch data in the component. I get an error message: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
Error occurs when I try to parse response: `await response.json()`
Did anything change regarding fetching data since version 241? And how to do it now?

index.svelte

```
<script>
     import { session } from '$app/stores';
     import { onMount } from 'svelte';

            onMount(async () => {
                    const response = await fetch('/content', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                user_id: $session.user.id
                            }),
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                        });
                        const data = await response.json(); // error occurs on this line
                });
</script>
```

index.js

```
export async function post({ request }) {
    const data = await request.json();
    try {
        if (data.user_id > 0) {
            let rows = await db.result;

            if (rows.length > 0) {
                return {
                    status: 200,
                    body: {
                        rows
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                };
            }

            return {
                status: 500,
                body: {
                    rows: [],
                    message: 'endp result err: ' + rows.message
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
        }

        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                rows: [],
                message: 'User not authorized'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: {
                rows: [],
                message: 'endp other err: ' + err.message
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Postman result of requesting endpoint

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" theme="white">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/charts/styles.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tiptap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Lighthouse - Login</title>
    <style data-svelte>
        .action-text.s-dYWHY7G7-e5q.s-dYWHY7G7-e5q {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 1rem
        }

        .action-text.s-dYWHY7G7-e5q>span.s-dYWHY7G7-e5q {
            margin-left: 0.75rem;
            vertical-align: top
        }

        .s-dYWHY7G7-e5q.s-dYWHY7G7-e5q {}

        .action-link.s-u1xw7poppUIF {
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            justify-content: center;
            padding-top: 10px
        }

        .s-u1xw7poppUIF {}

        .search-wrapper.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            max-width: 28rem;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0.5rem;
            height: 3rem;
            background-color: #393939;
            color: #fff;
            transition: max-width 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9),
                background 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        .search-wrapper-hidden.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            max-width: 3rem;
            background-color: #161616
        }

        .search-focus.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            outline: 2px solid #fff;
            outline-offset: -2px
        }

        .search-wrapper-2.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            display: flex;
            flex-grow: 1;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #393939
        }

        .btn-search.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            width: 3rem;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: background-color 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9),
                opacity 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        .btn-search-disabled.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            border: none;
            pointer-events: none
        }

        .input-search.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.375rem;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            color: #fff;
            caret-color: #fff;
            background-color: initial;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3rem;
            padding: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        .input-hidden.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none
        }

        .btn-clear.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            width: 3rem;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            opacity: 1;
            display: block;
            transition: background-color 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9),
                opacity 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        .btn-clear.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L:hover {
            background-color: #4c4c4c
        }

        .btn-clear-hidden.s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {
            opacity: 0;
            display: none
        }

        .s-DzH6K7xlQw-L {}

        .subject-divider.s-CDH0hzNq6wMb.s-CDH0hzNq6wMb {
            color: #525252;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #525252;
            margin: 32px 1rem 8px
        }

        .subject-divider.s-CDH0hzNq6wMb span.s-CDH0hzNq6wMb {
            font-size: 0.75rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1rem;
            letter-spacing: 0.32px;
            color: #c6c6c6
        }

        .s-CDH0hzNq6wMb.s-CDH0hzNq6wMb {}

        label.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            position: absolute;
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
            margin: -1px;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border: 0;
            visibility: inherit;
            clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        [role="search"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            max-width: 28rem;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0.5rem;
            height: 3rem;
            background-color: #393939;
            color: #fff;
            transition: max-width 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9),
                background 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        [role="search"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn:not(.active) {
            max-width: 3rem;
            background-color: #161616
        }

        [role="search"].active.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            outline: 2px solid #fff;
            outline-offset: -2px
        }

        [role="combobox"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            display: flex;
            flex-grow: 1;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #393939
        }

        input.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            width: 100%;
            height: 3rem;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.375rem;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            color: #fff;
            caret-color: #fff;
            background-color: initial;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: opacity 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        input.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn:not(.active) {
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none
        }

        button.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            width: 3rem;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: background-color 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9),
                opacity 0.11s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9)
        }

        .disabled.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            border: none;
            pointer-events: none
        }

        [aria-label="Clear search"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn:hover {
            background-color: #4c4c4c
        }

        .hidden.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            opacity: 0;
            display: none
        }

        ul.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10000;
            padding: 1rem 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 3rem;
            background-color: #161616;
            border: 1px solid #393939;
            border-top: none;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
        }

        [role="menuitem"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            padding: 6px 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 0.875rem;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 1.29;
            letter-spacing: 0.16px;
            transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9);
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            color: #c6c6c6
        }

        .selected.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn,
        [role="menuitem"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn:hover {
            background-color: #353535;
            color: #f4f4f4
        }

        [role="menuitem"].s-qIO5oRXzFdSn span.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {
            font-size: 0.75rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.34;
            letter-spacing: 0.32px;
            text-transform: lowercase;
            color: #c6c6c6
        }

        .s-qIO5oRXzFdSn.s-qIO5oRXzFdSn {}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="svelte">


        <div class="auth-bg">
            <div class="auth-box p-4 m-auto">

                <div>
                    <div><img src="/img/logo_orig.png" alt="logo" height="96"></div>
                        <div class="py-2">
                            <div class="bx--form-item bx--text-input-wrapper">
                                <label for="ccs-0.gurrqcw5ltk" class="false bx--label">
        Username
      </label>
                                <div class="bx--text-input__field-outer-wrapper">
                                    <div class="bx--text-input__field-wrapper">


                                        <input id="ccs-0.gurrqcw5ltk" placeholder="Enter username..." type="email" value="" class="bx--text-input   ">


      </div>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="py-2">
                                <div class="bx--form-item bx--text-input-wrapper">
                                    <label for="ccs-0.xn3g2icn4s7" class="false bx--label">
        Password
      </label>
                                    <div class="bx--text-input__field-outer-wrapper">
                                        <div class="bx--text-input__field-wrapper">


                                            <input id="ccs-0.xn3g2icn4s7" placeholder="Enter password..." type="password" value="" class="bx--text-input   ">


      </div>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-4">
                                    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="bx--btn bx--btn--primary">
    Log in</button></div>
                                <div class="py-2">or
                                    <a href="/auth/register" class="bx--link     ">Register</a></div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <a href="/auth/restore" class="bx--link     ">Forgot password?</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="company-logo"><a href="https://www.fh-swf.de/en/"
                                target="_blank"><img src="/img/company-logo.png" alt="company-logo" height="64"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bx--loading-overlay ">
                        <div aria-atomic="true" aria-labelledby="ccs-0.lnde8bksux9" aria-live="assertive"
                            class="bx--loading">
                            <label id="ccs-0.lnde8bksux9" class="bx--visually-hidden">Active loading indicator</label>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="bx--loading__svg">
                                <title>Active loading indicator</title>
                                <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="44" class="bx--loading__stroke"></circle>
                            </svg></div>
                    </div>


                    <script type="module" data-hydrate="1xenv5n">
                        import { start } from "/@fs/Users/elshad/OneDrive/Projects/FH-SWF/StudentAssistant/LighthouseApp/.svelte-kit/runtime/client/start.js";
        start({
            target: document.querySelector('[data-hydrate="1xenv5n"]').parentNode,
            paths: {"base":"","assets":""},
            session: {authenticated:false},
            route: true,
            spa: false,
            trailing_slash: "never",
            hydrate: {
                status: 200,
                error: null,
                nodes: [
                    import("/src/routes/auth/__layout.reset.svelte"),
                        import("/src/routes/auth/login/index.svelte")
                ],
                params: {}
            }
        });
    </script>
                    <script type="application/json" data-type="svelte-props">
                        {}
                    </script>
                </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your endpoint is returning some HTML (possibly a 404), hence the first character encountered being `<`, which isn't valid JSON. Have you tested your `/content` endpoint in isolation (with a tool like Postman or something similar)?

Comment: I tested with Postman right now, and indeed it returns HTML.  But that's a result, I don't get what is causing that.
It was working just fine before the version upgrade. I read all changelogs of SvelteKit from version 241 till 287, but could not find any changes related to my problem.
I have added endpoint code (index.js) to my question

Comment: Could you post what you get back from Postman as well, please? Including the HTTP status code, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Because requests from Postman are not authorized, endpoint returns Login page as HTML. Added to the question

Comment: Downgraded to a version 241, and it works again, both in browser, and in Postman

Comment: Rolled back on version 241 for now. However, it's not a solution. I will wait until some kind of clarification will arrive

Comment: I don't understand how Postman requests, specifically, would be authorized on one version and unauthorized in another. I think you have an auth/credentials/session issue somewhere else in your code that is caused by breaking changes between 241 and 287, but it's not part of the code you're showing. That issue likely causes your endpoint requests to redirect to the login page (which is what you see in Postman and why you get HTML in your response in Svelte) instead of being served by your endpoint handler as you would expect. I would look at where the redirect is triggered for clues.

Comment: I don't svelte version might be somehow related to the auth. Try clear browser cache and sign in again into your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `accept` headers as well to indicate to the server what you accept as a return, by default this is html.

```js
headers: {
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "accept": "application/json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to this? I stumbled upon it when researching how to Post files to the filestore.

[Breaking: use Request and Response objects in endpoints and hooks #3384](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3384)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31762855)